# Solving a congruence with an invertible piece

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

If I have

$$a \equiv bp^k \bmod p^e$$

for $0 \leq k \leq e$ with $a,p,k,e$ known.

How do I solve for $b$ given that $b$ is invertible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $a\equiv bp^k\pmod{p^e}$, it follows that $a=bp^k+cp^e$.  But, then it follows that $a$ is divisible by $p^k$.  Therefore, $a=dp^k$.  Then, $d\equiv b\pmod{p^{e-k}}$.

Comment: @user230040 Could you please clarify where you're confused.

Comment: From your set-up, it must be that $a$ is divisible by $p^k$, so $d=a/p^k$.

Comment: That's why I converted the statement back into a statement about integers using the definition for modular arithmetic.  If you're still confused, I suggest reviewing the definitions in modular arithmetic.